# Why are some exceptions a few levels deep?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

I have a simple entity insert as follows:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var item = new Artist();
    TryUpdateModel(item);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Artist.Add(item);
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            gvArtist.DataBind();
            gvArtist.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Master.Warning = e.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

e.Message and e.InnerException.Message both equate to:

"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."

But, e.InnerException.InnerException.Message gives the exception I'm looking for, which is:

"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_artist_Cuid'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.artist'. The duplicate key value is (11). The statement has been terminated."

I'm worried about missing other exceptions, or causing an exception if I just keep

```
Master.Warning = e.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
```

in play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fears are completely founded. Something like this is what you're looking for.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    while (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }

    Master.Message = ex.Message;
}
```

The reason for the errors being varying levels deep is that the errors can occur in different sections of code, and they may bubble up through a varying number of methods that wrap them inside other exceptions. You can't plan for them to come from a specific level.

Comment: After exiting the `while` loop `ex` would be null so `ex.Message` will throw `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Thanks. I was seconds away from going to bed and didn't catch that.